# Extend a Windows Form DateTimePicker in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls, datetimepicker, extends

I need to extend a DTP for adding some properties and for changing the behavior of some methods.
Especially I've to put a TextBox over the DTP and manage che Changing in DTP Value both for Textbox and for DTP.

So I've to override the CustomDateTimePicker_Value Changed event, but when I try to do it my app crashes without showing me any error message.

The code I'm trying to test is:

```
public void InitializeComponent()
{
    ...
    this.ValueChanged += MCCustomDateTimePicker_ValueChanged;
}


protected void MCCustomDateTimePicker_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtOnDTP.Text = this.Value.ToString();  
}
```

Where is the problem?
Thank you so much!

Comment: My crystal ball says that you also implemented the TextChanged event for txtOnDTP to update the Value.  That is likely to crash your program with this site's name.  Use a *bool* to break the recursion.

Comment: Your Crystal Ball at this time doesn't says the right thing :D :D :D
I had previously figure out that it would cause recursion, so I avoided implementing it!

If I change txtOnDTP.Text = this.Value.ToString(); 
with 
txtOnDTP.Text = this.Text;

it works, I can't understand what is the reason!